# How to access control in HTML defined inside FormArray in component - Angular2

Tags: angular, form-control, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I am using `ReactiveFroms` in my app. When I added `static` controls then every thing is working fine.
I am showing `validation` errors using `inbuilt` classes of `controls`.
Working [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/AZ5JgwkPYbccG7gHkgat?p=preview) with static controls.

But when I try to add `dynamic` controls then I am not able to access controls in order to apply `inbuilt` validation.

I am facing problem in accessing control `reference` from `HTML template` in order to apply validation. 
I am not able to figure it out how can I access controls.
Here is the plunkr for that.

Here is my template for adding dynamic controls:

```
  <form [formGroup]="valForm" class="form-validate form-horizontal"  >
<div formArrayName="banks">
     <div *ngFor="let bank of bankArray.controls;let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
        <legend>Bank Details</legend>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name of the Bank</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="Enter Bank Name" formControlName="bankName" [formControl]="valForm.controls['banks']" />
                <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="valForm.controls['bankName'].hasError('required') && (valForm.controls['bankName'].dirty || valForm.controls['bankName'].touched)">This field is required</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    </div>
 </div>
 <button (click)="addNewBank()">Add New Bank</button>
 </form>
```

I am not able to figure it out how I can access `formControl` in order to add validations. I tried various approach like:

```
       valForm.controls['banks'][bankName]; //Not working
       valForm.controls['banks'][0][bankName] //Not working

         <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="Enter Bank Name" formControlName="bankName" [formControl]="valForm.get('bankName')" />
                <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="valForm.controls['bankName'].hasError('required') && (valForm.get('bankName').dirty || valForm.get('bankName').touched)">This field is required</span> //Not working
```

Here is the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/j7IzMcBsazrhLjZAAO4D) for that.

Comment: use valForm.get('myControllName')

Comment: Please update plunker

Comment: @yurzui I don't know how can I access control in HTML that's why I haven't changed it. Are you talking about this plunker  https://plnkr.co/edit/j7IzMcBsazrhLjZAAO4D

Comment: `.get(['banks', i, 'bankName'])` where `i` is index https://plnkr.co/edit/BWrz6tTe9Smo2UR3pyIz?p=preview

Comment: Thnks @yurzui it is wokring fine (y)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see several options

```
valForm.get(['banks', i, 'bankName'])
valForm.get('banks.' + 'i' + '.bankName')

bankArray.get([i, 'bankName'])
bankArray.get(i + '.bankName')

bankArray.at(i).get('bankName')
```

Comment: I searched these in the linked which you gave some days ago https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#display-the-formarray . But I haven't succeeded to get this :( @yurzui